# MongoDb Query from nested documents

Tags: mongodb

```
{ _id: ObjectId("62d3af6d0df67535575ee87e"),
  time: '2022-07-17T09_39_19',
  data: 
   [ { Manufacturer: 'iPollo',
       Model: 'V1',
       Release: 'June 2022',
       'Size(mm)': { x: 314, y: 194, z: 290 },
       'Weight(g)': 13000,
       'Noise level': '70db',
       'Fan(s)': '4',
       'Power(w)': 3100,
       Interface: 'Ethernet',
       Memory: '6G',
       Temperature: '5 - 25 °C',
       Humidity: '10 - 90 %',
       coins: 
        [ 'Ubiq',
          'Ethereum',
          'Ethereum Classic',
          'Musicoin',
          'Pirl',
          'EtherGem',
          'Callisto',
          'QuarkChain' ],
       available_stores: 
        [ { store_name: 'CoinMining Central',
            url: 'https://coinminingcentral.com/collections/ipollo-miners/products/ipollo-v1-mini-ethereum-miner-3-6-gh-s?ref=uybdgyQD&ref=uybdgyQD',
            price: '$21,959.49',
            country: 'United Kingdom',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'AKMiner',
            url: 'https://www.akminer.com/all-products/ipollo-v1-3600mh-eth-miner-most-powerful-eth-miner-for-2022?wpam_id=1',
            price: '$20,399.00',
            country: 'China',
            stock: 'In stock(3 \ndays\n)',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'NHASH',
            url: 'https://www.nhash.net/miners/94129954756763648?ref=3yrntphlqn',
            price: '$20,999.00',
            country: 'Hong Kong',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'BT-Miners',
            url: 'https://bt-miners.com/products/2022-new-ipollo-v1-eth-etc-miner-3600mh-s-with-psu-and-cord-most-powerful-eth-miner-for-2022?ref=3yrntphlqn&ref=3yrntphlqn&variant=43048045183163',
            price: '$21,000.00',
            country: 'United States',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'ViperaTech',
            url: 'https://www.viperatech.com/product/ipollo-v1-eth-etc-miner-3600mh-s/?ref=585',
            price: '$21,900.00',
            country: 'Canada',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Safety Miner',
            url: 'https://www.safetyminer.net/product-page/ipollo-v1-3-6gh-s?ref=3yrntphlqn',
            price: '$25,103.16',
            country: 'United Kingdom',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Miner Bros',
            url: 'https://www.cryptominerbros.com/product/ipollo-v1-3600mh-s-eth-etc-miner/?wpam_id=1',
            price: '$27,499.00',
            country: 'Honk Kong',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'AsicMarketPlace',
            url: 'https://asicmarketplace.com/product/ipollo-v1-eth-miner-3600mh/?wpam_id=4',
            price: '$27,550.00',
            country: 'Honk Kong',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'MillionMiner',
            url: 'https://www.millionminer.com/ipollo-v1-3600mhs--ethereum-miner-new-millionminercom.html?1000',
            price: '$30,143.96',
            country: 'Germany',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Crypto Supply',
            url: 'https://cryptosupply.de/product/ipollo-v1/?wpam_id=1',
            price: '$30,900.08',
            country: 'Germany',
            stock: 'In stock(14 \ndays\n)',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Casa Miners',
            url: 'https://casaminers.com/collections/new-asic-1/products/ipollo-v1-3-6gh-s?ref=TTdMmJZNqvqtBI',
            price: '$31,242.85',
            country: 'Italia',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'iPollo',
            url: 'https://ipollo.com/products/ipollo-v?ref=3yrntphlqn',
            price: '$35,460.00',
            country: 'China',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Bitcoin Merch',
            url: 'https://bitcoinmerch.com/products/ipollo-v1-3-6gh-s-eth-asic-miner?aff=2',
            price: '$39,999.99',
            country: 'United States',
            stock: 'Out of stock',
            isFreeShipping: false } ],
       Algorithm_and_power: 
        [ { Algorithm_name: 'EtHash',
            'hashrate(H/hour) ': 3600000000,
            'power_consumption(W)': 3100 } ],
       available_mining_pools: 
        [ { pool_name: 'Poolin',
            url_link: 'https://www.poolin.com',
            profit_type: 'FPPS',
            profit_perc: 'FPPS' },
          { pool_name: 'SparkPool',
            url_link: 'https://www.sparkpool.com/',
            profit_type: 'PPS',
            profit_perc: 0.01 },
          { pool_name: 'Ethermine',
            url_link: 'https://ethermine.org',
            profit_type: 'PPLNS',
            profit_perc: 0.01 },
          { pool_name: 'ViaBTC',
            url_link: 'https://pool.viabtc.com?refer=731218',
            profit_type: 'PPS+',
            profit_perc: 0 },
          { pool_name: 'F2Pool',
            url_link: 'https://www.f2pool.com',
            profit_type: 'PPS+',
            profit_perc: 0.03 } ] },
     { Manufacturer: 'Jasminer',
       Model: 'X4',
       Release: 'November 2021',
       'Noise level': '75db',
       'Fan(s)': '4',
       'Power(w)': 1200,
       Interface: 'Ethernet',
       Memory: '5G',
       Temperature: '5 - 40 °C',
       Humidity: '5 - 95 %',
       coins: 
        [ 'Ubiq',
          'Ethereum',
          'Ethereum Classic',
          'Musicoin',
          'Pirl',
          'EtherGem',
          'Callisto',
          'QuarkChain' ],
       available_stores: 
        [ { store_name: 'Safety Miner',
            url: 'https://www.safetyminer.net/product-page/jasminer-x4-2-6gh-1200w?ref=3yrntphlqn',
            price: '$20,163.18',
            country: 'United Kingdom',
            stock: 'Out of stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Jingle Mining',
            url: 'https://www.jinglemining.com/products/jasminer-x4-etchash-server?ref=3yrntphlqn&variant=42041025233122',
            price: '$20,499.00',
            country: 'China',
            stock: 'Pre-order(Jun 2022)',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'ViperaTech',
            url: 'https://www.viperatech.com/product/jasminer-x4-etchash-server/?ref=585',
            price: '$21,000.00',
            country: 'Canada',
            stock: 'In stock',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'AKMiner',
            url: 'https://akminer.com/all-products/jasminer-x4-etchash-server-jan-shipment?wpam_id=1',
            price: '$23,999.00',
            country: 'China',
            stock: 'Used',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'BT-Miners',
            url: 'https://bt-miners.com/collections/eth-miners/products/jasminer-x4-etc-eth-5g-miner-2500mh-s-mine-eth-till-june-2022?ref=3yrntphlqn&ref=3yrntphlqn&variant=42969029378235',
            price: '$24,459.00',
            country: 'United States',
            stock: 'Used',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'NHASH',
            url: 'https://www.nhash.net/miners/99141979488657408?ref=3yrntphlqn',
            price: '$24,999.00',
            country: 'Hong Kong',
            stock: 'Pre-order(May 2022)',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'CoinMining Central',
            url: 'https://coinminingcentral.com/collections/jasminer/products/jasminer-x4-eth-ethereum-miner-2500mh?ref=uybdgyQD',
            price: '$29,674.99',
            country: 'United Kingdom',
            stock: 'Pre-order(Jul 2022)',
            isFreeShipping: false },
          { store_name: 'Bitcoin Merch',
            url: 'https://bitcoinmerch.com/products/jasminer-x4-2-5-gh-s-ethereum-miner?aff=2',
            price: '$51,999.99',
            country: 'United States',
            stock: 'In stock(30 \ndays\n)',
            isFreeShipping: false } ],
       Algorithm_and_power: 
        [ { Algorithm_name: 'EtHash',
            'hashrate(H/hour) ': 2500000000,
            'power_consumption(W)': 1200 },
          { Algorithm_name: 'EtHashETC',
            'hashrate(H/hour) ': 2500000000,
            'power_consumption(W)': 1200 } ],
       available_mining_pools: 
        [ { pool_name: 'Poolin',
            url_link: 'https://www.poolin.com',
            profit_type: 'FPPS',
            profit_perc: 'FPPS' },
          { pool_name: 'SparkPool',
            url_link: 'https://www.sparkpool.com/',
            profit_type: 'PPS',
            profit_perc: 0.01 },
          { pool_name: 'Ethermine',
            url_link: 'https://ethermine.org',
            profit_type: 'PPLNS',
            profit_perc: 0.01 },
          { pool_name: 'ViaBTC',
            url_link: 'https://pool.viabtc.com?refer=731218',
            profit_type: 'PPS+',
            profit_perc: 0 },
          { pool_name: 'F2Pool',
            url_link: 'https://www.f2pool.com',
            profit_type: 'PPS+',
            profit_perc: 0.03 } ] },
```

I have this collection in my mongodb database, and when I query data from it, like for example `.find("data.Manufacturer":"iPollo")` because its nested documents, it returns for me the entire document, is there any way where I could return only the object from the array without like hardcoding it (getting the entire data liste and  iterate through it to find the query I am searching for)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"data.Manufacturer": "iPollo"}},
  {$set: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.Manufacturer", "iPollo"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$first: "$data"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dWTUJEayBVK)